# onmousemove attribute not working in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Having the **onmousemove** attribute inside div tag on the front-end side of the electron app doesn't work.

This is the exact code used. knowing that the same script runs flawlessly on chrome. BrowserWindow runs with the initial value preset, but doesn't change according to mouse movement.

```
<div
  style="background:black; height:605;width:400;"
  onmousemove="lfo.frequency.value = event.clientY;"
>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you getting any error. It should work.

I tried with the following code using onmousemove event listener, its working. So I believe the problem is not with mousemove listener.

Try the following code and check whether its working

```
        <div
          style="background:black; height:605;width:400;border:1px solid"
          onmousemove="alert(event.clientY)"
        >
        oii
        </div>
```

The complete working code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log('about')
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1>
    <div
      style="background:black; height:605;width:400;border:1px solid"
      onmousemove="onmove(event)"
    >
    oii
    </div>
    <p id="text"></p>
    <p>Hello!!!</p>
    <script>
      function onmove(event){
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = event.clientY;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```